# Can't key value to nested json in python

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array, nested

I could not append the data to nested json in python

```
products = {}
results_hash = {}
variations_hash = {} 
varaitions_array = []
variations_hash = varaitions_array
results_array = variations_hash

products["results"] = results_hash
products["results"]["variations"] = variations_hash

fname = "mouna"
lname = "raj"

sname = "kumar"
slname = "vel"

variations_hash[fname] = lname
variations_hash[sname] = slname

print products
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    variations_hash[fname] = lname
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Expected output:

```
{'results': {'variations': [{'Mouna': 'raj'}
,{'kumar': 'vel'}
]}}
```

What changes to be made in the script

Comment: Your `variations_hash` seems to be a list not a dictionary. Same in your sample output. Lists are indexed by integers not by strings (like `"mouna"`).

Answer (score 1):

```
Due to the line: variations_hash = varaitions_array
variations_hash is now a list and not a dictionary any more.
Hence, the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since variations_hash is a list, and not a dictionary, you might want to iterate through the list and then get the keys.